# Halachot within the means of Hypnosis

Tags: halacha

Within the laws of Halacha, are there any Halachot which state that a Jewish person may or may not be allowed to be hypnotized for any reason, whether it is because of a fear or phobia or whether other reasons.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16351/are-you-culpable-for-things-done-under-hypnosis

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9614/hypnosis-in-halacha